# Microservice deployment in Kubernetes by node wise

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy my set of microservices in different nodes. For installing kubeadm and creation of clusters I am following the below documentations.

1. https://medium.com/@SystemMining/setup-kubenetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-kubeadm-336f4061d929
2. https://medium.com/@Grigorkh/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-1ac2ef522a36
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_fOIELGMDY&t=108s

I need one master with 2 worker machines. I got clear idea about how to create the kubernetes clusters.

**My requirements:**  I have an application which has separate set of microservices. I need to deploy docker images for one set of microservices into one node1.And docker images for other set into node2. And 3 rd set of microservices in node3...etc...This is my planning of deployment. Please correct me if I am going in wrong direction, Since I only started exploration in docker, kubernetes and jenkins. Devop.

**My confusions:**

1. According to my requirement region wise deployment by nodes , Is this deployment strategy is possible by Kubernetes ?  And is this one of the standard way ?
2. If I am using Jenkins for implementing CI/CD pipeline , then Do I need to install Jenkins in each Vm? Means master machine and also in machine which resides nodes?

These all are my confusion about this Kubernetes deployment. Please correct me if my thoughts are wrong, since I am only a beginner in DevOp world. How can I clarify my doubts about deployment by using Kubernetes ?

Comment: Are node1,2,3 in separate regions in your cluster?

Comment: No . In same region.

Comment: ok, thats confusing now, but your original statement says: `deploy docker images for one region into one node1.And docker images for other region into node2`

Comment: Region means - I have separate set of education departments. each set of department have different set of activities. So I just called as a separate set . The word region , I accidently added here. Actually I meant different set. Let me correct question. Sorry for misleading idea.

Comment: No worries, what you mean is each is a "tenant"!

Comment: Ok .thank you. that the thing i really trying to express. Is possible like that way- one set of microservices in one node. And another set of microservices in node2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question - you basically need to allocate each node for a tenant. If there are compliance/regulatory reasons then you should do it (Though it won't be very efficient). Here is how you can do it:

On the node1 add a taint:

```
kubectl taint nodes node1.compute.companyname.com reservedfor=tenant1:NoSchedule
```

What above means is that the node1 will only schedule pods which have a matching toleration and not any other pod. For the microservice which you need to schedule on node1, you will have to add a toleration to the pod YAML file like:

```
tolerations:
- key: "reservedfor"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "tenant1"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

The same logic can be extended - so that even if tenant1 needs 4 machines, then all the 4 machines can be tainted with above key value pair and then pods can be tolerated on those nodes. Check out the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) and [blog with an example here](http://blog.infracloud.io/advanced-scheduling-kubernetes/)

You can also use the [pod/node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) to achieve above.

Your second question on Jenkins - No, you don't need to install Jenkins on each node, but other than that more details are needed for that question.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your reponse sir. Let me clear that in your statement - " If there are compliance/regulatory reasons then you should do it (Though it won't be very efficient)". What is this means ? How I can identify that I need to add this node as a tenant by this method?

Comment: What I mean is if you run only one microservice on a node which is bigger capacity, then rest of capacity is underutilized. The whole idea is container is to use resources effectively!

Comment: Ya. I got idea. Let me explore this all your points. Thank you for your responses and guidance Mr. Vishal Biyani.